# What are the generated files when creating a table in MySQL (.opt, .frm, .MYD, .MYI)

Tags: php, mysql, database

When I create a database in MySQL and create a table called `flat` in it, 4 files are generated:

```
 db.opt
 flats.frm
 flats.MYD
 flats.MYI
```

This happens every time a table is created.
What are these files?

Comment: What are you asking? Where is your code?

Comment: `flats.MYI` is an index file, for the table indexes; `.MYD` has your table data; and `.frm` has the table definition.... for `MyISAM` tables.... [MySQL Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/myisam-introduction.html)

Comment: not there code I create table from GUI  phpMyAdmin so that no needing for code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file `db.opt` contains the [database characteristics](http://Database%20characteristics%20are%20stored%20in%20the%20db.opt%20file%20in%20the%20database%20directory). It is updated every time the database is altered.

For the remaining 3 files:

- *table*.frm - [Describes the table's format](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/frm-file-format.html) (it is created regardless of the storage engine being used)
- *table*.MYI - [Contains the MyISAM table index information](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/the-myi-file.html) (created for MyISAM storage engine)
- *table*.MYD - [Contains the MyISAM table data](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/myisam-introduction.html) (created for MyISAM storage engine)

Comment: that's right but db.opt file content only this line.
default-character-set=utf8 default-collation=utf8_general_ci.

Comment: @AlyAhmedMohamed yes, and that's correct. `charset` and `collation` are characteristics of the database, so they're saved inside the `db.opt` file.